# select element validation on popup using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an asp.net web application with a div opening as popup. On popup, select elements are being generated dynamically.
Resulant html looks like this (data-id is different for each select):

```html
<div class="header">
    <div>Please select the options for your product.</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="formfield clearfix">
        Topping
        <select id="items" data-id="1">
            <option value="0">Select</option>
            <option 1="">Strawberry</option>
            <option 2="">Apple Pie</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="formfield clearfix">
        Size
        <select id="items" data-id="2">
            <option value="0">Select</option>
            <option 3="">Small</option>
            <option 4="">Medium</option>
            <option 5="">Large</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
    <a href="javascript:$('#product-options').submit();" class="btn btn-orange-2ln"><span>Continue Shopping</span></a>
    <a href="javascript:$('#product-options').submit();" class="btn btn-red-2ln"><span>Checkout</span></a>
</div>
<div id="error">Not selected!</div>
<div id="valid">Validated!</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

I want to make sure that an item is selected from each dropdown. Otherwise error div will appear.

Here is the jQuery which I am using:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#product-options').submit(function (e) {
        debugger;
        var check = $('#items').val()
        if (check == '0') {
            $('#error').show();
            $('#valid').hide();
        } else {
            $('#error').hide();
            $('#valid').show();
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('#mySelect').change(function (e) {
        $('#result').html($('#items option:selected').text());
    })
});
```

update:

Razor view

```
<div id="dvContents" style="display: none">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "product-options" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary()

        <div id="error">Not selected!</div>
        <div id="valid">Validated!</div>
        <div id="result"></div>

        @Html.Hidden("ItemId", @Model.ItemID)
        @Html.Hidden("QuantityLimit", @Model.QuantityLimit)
        <div class="header">
            <div>Please select the options for your product.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            @foreach (var item in Model.AssociatedItemOptions)
            {
                <div class="formfield clearfix">
                    @item.OptionName.Trim()
                    <select id="items" class="items" data-id="@item.ItemOptionID">
                        <option value="0">Select</option>
                        @foreach (var option in item.OptionValues)
                        {
                            <option @option.ItemOptionValueID>@option.Value</option>
                        }
                    </select>

                </div>

            }
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-orange-2ln"><span>Continue Shopping</span></a>
            <a href="javascript:$('#product-options').submit();" class="btn btn-red-2ln"><span>Checkout</span></a>
        </div>
    }

    @*  @if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.SelectedItem))
    { <span>Selected Item : @Model.SelectedItem</span> } - *@
</div>



 $('a.btn').click(function (e) {
        debugger;
        $('#error').hide();
        $('#valid').show();
        $('select').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "0") {
                $('#error').show();
                $('#valid').hide();
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            else {
                $('#product-options').submit();
            }
        });

    });
    $('select').change(function (e) {
        $('#result').html($(this).find('option:selected').text());
    })
```

But it is not working. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You have duplicate ids for select. due to which ,`$('#items').val()` will get the value of first select only. Try this:

```
 $('#error').hide();
 $('#valid').show();
 $('select').each(function(){
    if($(this).val()=="0"){
      $('#error').show();
      $('#valid').hide();
    }
 });
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4J9HY/)**

Comment: @DotnetSparrow: that is beacuase submit is not getting called.check the fiddle

Comment: please check updated question. i tried the script and it is not working with href click. although form is posted even nothing is selected

Comment: @DotnetSparrow: you need to wrap that script in DOM ready event too.

Comment: I wrapped but still form is posted and if i remove href, then it adds # to url only

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in these:

```html
<select id="items" data-id="1">
```

Those `id` attributes have to be unique.

Either replace them by classes:

```html
<select class="items" data-id="1">:
```

Or number them:

```html
<select id="items1" data-id="1">
```

Then modify your JavaScript:

```
$('.items').each(function(){ // (This works best with `class="items"`)
    if($(this).val()=="0"){
        $('#error').show();
        $('#valid').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: can i do it with data-id ?

Comment: You could, but that'd be very inefficient, not to mention more code.